# strange behavior when trying to update crud

Tags: reactjs

I have a strange behavior that I believe is because I am starting now at REACT.

in my update I can show a modal with all the data I have in my database 
`defaultValue={this.state.user.username}`
my modal opens with the data OK, then I do as in my CREATE that is working.
`onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}`

but in my update method I try to print my `<Form onSubmit={this.update}>` data in `JSON.stringify` and just receive the data I entered in the input. if i have 2 fields and just edited one he just brings me 1 of them, he should bring me the other field too!

Constructor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            user: { id: '', username: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', lang: '' }
        }
    }
```

FROM

```
<Form onSubmit={this.update}>
  <Row form>
    <Col md={4}>
       <FormGroup>
          <Label>Username</Label>
             <Input
               type="email"
               name="username"
               defaultValue={this.state.user.username}
               onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} />
        </FormGroup>
     </Col>
etc...
```

Update method

```
update = async e => {
e.preventDefault();
const { username, firstName, lastName } = this.state;

const json = JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    lang: 'EN'
})
console.log(json)
etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize your state with the array `users` and an object `user`. Then you call setState to update `username` but username doesn't exist at the root of your state.

you should call setState this way to update user.username:

```
this.setState({ user: { username: e.target.value } })
```

and if you want to preserve the other properties of state.user:

```
this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, username: e.target.value } })
```

By the way, if you're starting with React, forget about component classes, you should learn how to write functional components

Comment: I will follow your advice, I started 3 days ago.
the code works, thanks.